# Deploy dist folder to heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I extract the necessary files to the dist folder using react webpack.

my file directory

```
dist
    --index.js
    --index.html
src
..source files
```

When I deploy the application to heroku I get an error like this

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=beverlylaurel.herokuapp.com request_id=bfc941e7-4d93-446d-8edf-a723dddbe990 fwd="95.70.130.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=beverlylaurel.herokuapp.com request_id=3d3e5881-4397-4c35-ab19-d5ff3534bcad fwd="95.70.130.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "xapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ramonak/react-progress-bar": "^2.1.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "i18next": "^19.9.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pure-react-carousel": "^1.27.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-avatar": "^3.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^4.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "storage-helper": "^1.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development --progress",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --progress"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.5",
    "npm": "7.6.3"
  }
}
```

webpack config file

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/.css$|.scss$|.sass$/],
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(j|t)sx?$|.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react", "@babel/typescript"],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,

        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
      filename: "index.html",
      favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/favicon.png"),
      // publicPath: "/dist/",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: "react",
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".wasm", ".ts", ".tsx", ".mjs", ".cjs", ".js", ".json"],
    alias: {
      Features: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/features/"),
      Helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/helpers/"),
      Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/routes/"),
      Redux: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/redux/"),
      I18n: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/i18n/i18n.js"),
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/"),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/components/"),
      Enum: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/enumerations/enums.tsx"),
      Services: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/services/"),
      Layout: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/layout/"),
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'Redux/store';

//app
import App from './App';

//i18n
import 'I18n';

//assets
import 'Assets/css/base.css';
import 'Assets/css/elements.css';
import 'Assets/css/helpers.css';
import 'Assets/css/_normalize.css';

ReactDOM.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
      </Provider>
   </React.StrictMode>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Using the start command I am successfully working locally

where am I doing wrong? I'm not putting the webpack config file here to avoid crowding, but if you want, I can.

I want it to work from the dist folder on Heroku

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs might help

Comment: @vanshaj Thank you for trying to help. Deploy process is successful, but when I go to my application from heroku, Application error appears.

when i look at error using heroku logs --tail

I see the error heroku [router]: at = error code = H10

Comment: I've been dealing with this error for 3 days and I'm freaked out

Comment: Is the code opensource ? I can try deploying it myself

Comment: @vanshaj :/ unfortunately not open source. but I can add the files you want from me. or how else can I contact you. I'm stuck here and I haven't been able to move forward for days

Comment: heroku automatically runs `npm build` before running ` npm start` script so you want your start script to be a node server listening to the port given by heroku using environment variable (shouldn't be hardcoded in your application). you shouldn't use webpack server for the start script too. A node process starting a file in the build folder would suffice

Comment: if you understand more
If it helps, I added my package.json and webpack config file to the question content.

Comment: Can you also post src/index.js

Comment: @vanshaj thank you for your attention. I added index.js to the question content

Comment: I think it is because you are not using the port provided by heroku but have hardcoded it to 3000. Remove the hardcoded port and use the process.env.PORT variable, create an .env file and try running it locally . ref : https://dev.to/th3n0m4d/environment-variables-and-devserver-2g4o

Comment: @vanshaj i changed it as in the document but it still doesn't work. I understand that the port information is valid for devServer. I cannot set such information in prod mode. I can successfully build and open the application locally.

Comment: but forget it. I took too much of your time. Thank you very much for your help. there is nothing to do.

Comment: Its okay, it happens to all of us. I would suggest following a tutorial in which a node app is created and deployed on heroku. If you're still stuck feel free to ping me here on SO or on my linkedin. I would be happy to help

Comment: @vanshaj thank you. Can you give the link to your linked in profile? I want to show you the codes

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/vanshajgirotra/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact error and in my case, the problem was the .gitignore file. It had specified to ignore the build folder and that's why my dist wasn't pushed to heroku. After changing it I just had to commit and push the missing files and it worked perfectly.

They suggest a starting .gitignore file to look like this:

```
/node_modules
npm-debug.log
.DS_Store
/*.env
```

Hope it helps someone as I see that the problem wasn't resolved :)

Comment: You probably want to ignore your build and dist files, as compiling should not but done locally - it should done in the prod env. i.e. you don't want the compiling to be done differently on your machine to how its done by other people / by your pipeline.